# Как написать кастомный массив(двухсвязный список) на си, который будет иметь разные типы элементов | Как присвоить переменной тип

Tags: c, типы

Мне нужно создать массив, типо как list в питоне.
Вот структура ноды

```
struct Node {
    Node* next = NULL;
    Node* prev= NULL;
    void* data;
};
```

Если я кладу в `data` указатель на строку, то могу делать операции с ней просто указав в скобочках её тип, `(char*)`.
Я пока вижу один вариант, это добавить в ноду строку, который будет обозначать тип, но тогда придёться каждый раз парсить что находиться в строке, и в функцию этот парсинг не засунешь, потому что я не могу присвоить в переменную тип. Подскажите как лучше это реализовать, может быть я вообще не в том направлении иду.

Comment: В си, в общем-то, только так и делается.  Только вместо строки тип обычно является перечислением.

Comment: Используя `с++` можно применять `implicit` и `explicit` операторы - переназначив операторы - будет проще работать.